# Can't build apk with buildozer

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, buildozer

I'm having some tough time trying to build an App with buildozer and kivy.
My app has three requirements: requests, kivy and datetime.
When building the app directly i get the following error:

```
# Install distribute
# Run 'curl http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py | venv/bin/python'
# Cwd /home/USER/python/ZugGit/ZugAppFahrt/.buildozer
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
# Install requirement requests in virtualenv
# Run 'pip install --download-cache=/home/USER/.buildozer/cache --target=/home/USER/python/ZugGit/ZugAppFahrt/.buildozer/applibs requests'
# Cwd /home/USER/python/ZugGit/ZugAppFahrt/.buildozer

Usage:   
pip install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...
pip install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options] ...
pip install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...
pip install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
pip install [options] <archive url/path> ...

no such option: --download-cache
# Command failed: pip install --download-cache=/home/USER/.buildozer/cache --target=/home/USER/python/ZugGit/ZugAppFahrt/.buildozer/applibs requests
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

I had read a lot and found out that the issue is in the --download-cache command.

So I deleted this part from the **init**.py file in the buildozer folder but now I got the following error:

```
# Cwd /home/USER/python/ZugGit/ZugAppFahrt/.buildozer
Directory '/home/USER/python/ZugGit/ZugAppFahrt/.buildozer/applibs' is not installable. File 'setup.py' not found.
# Command failed: pip install --target=/home/USER/.buildozer/cach/home/USER/python/ZugGit/ZugAppFahrt/.buildozer/applibs
```

I'm totally new to this and can't figure out what's the problem. What can I do that my App is build correctly. If I build the App without only with kivy as requirement, the app is built but crashes at start due to the lack of requests.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: The problem was that I've introduced a whitespace by deleting the "--download-cache" part.

However I've ran into a new problem. Now I got the following error:

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/USER/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/tools/ant/build.xml:377: SDK Platform Tools component is missing. Please install it with the SDK Manager (tools/android)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "build.py", line 517, in <module>
make_package(args)
File "build.py", line 365, in make_package
subprocess.check_call([ANT, arg])
File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 561, in check_call
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ant', 'debug']' returned non-zero exit status 1
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 build.py --name ZugFart --version 0.1 --package org.zugfart.fart --private "/home/USER/python/ZugGit/ZugAppFahrt/.buildozer/android/app" --sdk 19 --minsdk 9 --permission INTERNET --orientation portrait debug
```

The funny thing is that I somehow introduced a new error in buildozer, since I also can't build the app without the requirements anymore.

Comment: Post the full failing build log following your modifications to buildozer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I was able to fix the first issue and face a new one. I've edited my initial entry.

Comment: Okay, I don't know why, but I was able to get rid of the error by deleting all .buildozer files in the app folder. The build process seems to work now with all requirements. Nevertheless, the App crash on start complaining that the 'requests' module is missing. It seems that have to learn more about building an android app ;-)